# Accidentaly deleted ubuntu-destop while "sudo apt-get autoremove"

Tags: unity, apt, dependencies, kde

While doing `sudo apt-get autoremove` I accidentally deleted ubuntu-desktop. Have KDE installed, but like to switch them for diffenrent reasons (unity - work, kde - surfing the net). So, while trying to install ubuntu-desktop, I have this output:

```
tukanoid@tukanoid-Inspiron-5545:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for tukanoid: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried to do `sudo apt-get -f install` have this output:

```
tukanoid@tukanoid-Inspiron-5545:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After `sudo dpkg --configure -a` nothing happens.
I also tried to install ubuntu-desktop via `aptitude` but I get this message, and I really don't like it:

```
tukanoid@tukanoid-Inspiron-5545:~$ sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  checkbox-converged{a} checkbox-gui{a} liboxideqt-qmlplugin{a} liboxideqtcore0{ab} 
  liboxideqtquick0{a} libqt5organizer5{ab} libubuntugestures5{ab} libubuntutoolkit5{ab} 
  libunity-webapps0{a} python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-components{ab} 
  qml-module-ubuntu-layouts{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-test{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-web{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin{a} ubuntu-desktop unity-webapps-common{a} 
  unity-webapps-qml{a} unity-webapps-service{a} webapp-container{ab} webbrowser-app{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.1 MB/35.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 138 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
"Many packages, that are installed"
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Keep the following packages at their current version:    
1)      checkbox-converged [Not Installed]                     
2)      checkbox-gui [Not Installed]                           
3)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                   
4)      liboxideqtcore0 [Not Installed]                        
5)      liboxideqtquick0 [Not Installed]                       
6)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                       
7)      libubuntugestures5 [Not Installed]                     
8)      libubuntutoolkit5 [Not Installed]                      
9)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                      
10)     python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [Not Installed]             
11)     qml-module-ubuntu-components [Not Installed]           
12)     qml-module-ubuntu-layouts [Not Installed]              
13)     qml-module-ubuntu-test [Not Installed]                 
14)     qml-module-ubuntu-web [Not Installed]                  
15)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]
16)     ubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                         
17)     unity-webapps-common [Not Installed]                   
18)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                      
19)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                  
20)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                       
21)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

And finally after `sudo apt-get install qtbase-abi-5-5-1` I get:

```
tukanoid@tukanoid-Inspiron-5545:~$ sudo apt-get install qtbase-abi-5-5-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qtbase-abi-5-5-1 is a virtual package provided by:
  libqt5core5a 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 [Not candidate version]
  libqt5core5a 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'qtbase-abi-5-5-1' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What's the problem with the steps `aptitude` suggests?

Comment: It does nothing, and after I choose 'n'  aptitude suggests me to remove, downgrade many packages and also do nothing to those, that I really need to install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Right, but if you had chosen 'Y', hadn't it just installed those 21 packages (including `ubuntu-desktop`)?

Comment: Btw, I guess that `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` would suggest installing the same 21 packages.

Comment: No, it wont, it says "Keep the following packages at their current version", and I have those packages as "[Not Installed]", so, it won't do anything.

Comment: The output is somewhat confusing, but please try the command I suggested then.

Comment: And I showed, what output did I have while trying to install ubuntu-desktop whith apt-get (first)

Comment: `apt`and `apt-get` are not exactly the same.

Comment: I actually tried them both but get the same error

Comment: Maybe your packages are out of order somehow. Then please try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: I tried, nothing happened

Comment: No errors and no updated packages?

Comment: yes, and I don't understand why, I looked in synaptic, and there ubuntu-desktop is broken package, but apt -f install does nothing

Comment: Then try `sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop` (and try to install it after that).

Comment: that does nothing too

Comment: Please define "nothing". What does it respond?

Comment: Please show us the output of 'apt-cache policy' for checkbox-gui

Comment: tukanoid@tukanoid-Inspiron-5545:~$ sudo apt-cache policy checkbox-gui
checkbox-gui:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.4-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.2.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed *kubuntu PPA* without downgrading other packages. To do so add it again and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```